# Most efficient way to store and retrieve a 512-bit number?

Tags: c#, bitarray

I have a String of 512 characters that contains only 0, 1. I'm trying to represent it into a data structure that can save the space. Is BitArray the most efficient way?

I'm also thinking about using 16 int32 to store the number, which would then be 16 * 4 = 64 bytes.

Comment: Why not parse it into a `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient can mean many different things...

1. Most efficient from a memory management perspective?
2. Most efficient from a CPU calculation perspective?
3. Most efficient from a usage perspective? (In respect to writing code that uses the numbers for calculations)

For 1 - use `byte[64]` or `long[8]` - if you aren't doing calculations or don't mind writing your own calculations.

For 3 definitely `BigInteger` is the way to go.  You have your math functions already defined and you just need to turn your binary number into a decimal representation.

**EDIT:** Sounds like you don't want BigInteger due to size concerns... however I think you are going to find that you will of course have to parse this as an enumerable / yield combo where you are parsing it a bit at a time and don't hold the entire data structure in memory at the same time.

That being said... I can help you somewhat with parsing your string into array's of Int64's...  Thanks King King for part of this linq statement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18140063/2270839).

```
// convert string into an array of int64's
// Note that MSB is in result[0]
var result = input.Select((x, i) => i)
                .Where(i => i % 64 == 0)
                .Select(i => input.Substring(i, input.Length - i >= 64 ? 
                    64 : input.Length - i))
                .Select(x => Convert.ToUInt64(x, 2))
                .ToArray();
```

If you decide you want a different array structure `byte[64]` or whatever it should be easy to modify.

**EDIT 2:** OK I got bored so I wrote an EditDifference function for fun...  here you go...

```
static public int GetEditDistance(ulong[] first, ulong[] second)
{
    int editDifference = 0;
    var smallestArraySize = Math.Min(first.Length, second.Length);
    for (var i = 0; i < smallestArraySize; i++)
    {
        long signedDifference;
        var f = first[i];
        var s = second[i];
        var biggest = Math.Max(f, s);
        var smallest = Math.Min(f, s);
        var difference = biggest - smallest;
        if (difference > long.MaxValue)
        {
            editDifference += 1;
            signedDifference = Convert.ToInt64(difference - long.MaxValue - 1);
        }
        else
            signedDifference = Convert.ToInt64(difference);
        editDifference += Convert.ToString(signedDifference, 2)
            .Count(x => x == '1');
    }
    // if arrays are different sizes every bit is considered to be different
    var differenceOfArraySize = 
        Math.Max(first.Length, second.Length) - smallestArraySize;
    if (differenceOfArraySize > 0)
        editDifference += differenceOfArraySize * 64;
    return editDifference;
}
```

Comment: Calculation is important to me. I would like to calculate the edit distance between two numbers. Also, I got about 100 million of those numbers, and therefore, the size of the file also matters a lot. 100 million * 64 bytes ~ 6GB

Comment: For two binary strings with 0, 1, it could simply be the number of bits that they differ from each other.

Comment: @Yang was my answer helpful?  Do you consider it the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient would be having eight `UInt64`/`ulong` or `Int64`/`long` typed variables (or a single array), although this might not be optimal for querying/setting. One way to get around this is, indeed, to use a `BitArray` (which is basically a wrapper around the former method, including additional overhead [1]). It's a matter of choice either for easy use or efficient storage.

If this isn't sufficient, you can always choose to apply compression, such as RLE-encoding or various other widely available encoding methods (gzip/bzip/etc...). This will require additional processing power though.

It depends on your definition of efficient.

[1] Addtional overhead, as in storage overhead. BitArray internally uses an `Int32`-array to store values. In addition to that `BitArray` stores its current mutation version, the number of ints 'allocated' and a syncroot. Even though the overhead is negligible for smaller amount of values, it can be an issue if you keep a lot of these in memory.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "additional overhead" required by `BitArray`? Do you mean that a BitArray requires more memory or storage? Or that manipulating a BitArray is slower than doing the same thing with a `long[]`?

Comment: Added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use BigInteger from .NET. It can easily support 512-bit numbers as well as operations on those numbers.

```
BigInteger.Parse("your huge number");
```

Answer (score 0):

`BitArray` (with 512 bits), `byte[64]`, `int[16]`, `long[8]` (or `List<>` variants of those), or `BigInteger` will all be much more efficient than your `String`. I'd say that `byte[]` is the most idiomatic/typical way of representing data such as this, in general. For example, [`ComputeHash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) uses `byte[]` and [`Stream`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) deal with `byte[]`s, and if you store this data as a BLOB in a DB, `byte[]` will be the most natural way to work with that data. For that reason, it'd probably make sense to use this.

On the other hand, if this data represents a number that you might do numeric things to like addition and subtraction, you probably want to use a [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).

These approaches have roughly the same performance as each other, so you should choose between them based primarily on things like what makes sense, and secondarily on performance benchmarked in your usage.